# How many document allowed in one request Azure search While creating new actions `IndexBatch.New(actions)`?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I'm not getting Azure max limit document post in one Request.

Just I Want to know is there any official link that shows the max limit per indexer in the azure server as per the purchased plan [Click me](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/search/).

Here the azure Offical Indexer limits [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#indexer-limits)

> Below the Code for creating batches

```
public virtual void PostBulkDataToAssortmentIndex(ISearchFilterResult result)
{
    var itemFilters = _searchManager.GetAllFilters();

    IEnumerable<ISearchItem> items;
    List<IndexAction<AzureSearchItem>> actionList = new List<IndexAction<AzureSearchItem>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Items.Count; i = i + 32000)
    {
        actionList.Clear();
        items = result.Items.Skip(i).Take(32000);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            actionList.Add(IndexAction.MergeOrUpload(FormatSearchItem(item, itemFilters)));
        }

        // Post documents to index
        PostBulkAssortmentDocuments(actionList.AsEnumerable());
    }
}
public virtual void PostBulkAssortmentDocuments(IEnumerable<IndexAction<AzureSearchItem>> actions)
{
    var batch = IndexBatch.New(actions);

    try
    {
        var data = GetIndexClient(IndexName).Documents.Index(batch);
        var passResultCount = data.Results.Where(x => x.Succeeded).Count();
        var failResultCount = data.Results.Where(x => x.Succeeded == false).Count();
        var MessageResult = data.Results.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ErrorMessage));
        var keyResult = data.Results.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Key)).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
        var unikKey = keyResult.Distinct().ToList();
    }
    catch (IndexBatchException e)
    {
        // Sometimes when your Search service is under load, indexing will fail for some of the documents in
        // the batch. Depending on your application, you can take compensating actions like delaying and
        // retrying. For this simple demo, we just log the failed document keys and continue.
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Failed to index some of the documents: {0}",
            String.Join(", ", e.IndexingResults.Where(r => !r.Succeeded).Select(r => r.Key)));
    }
}
```

**Note:** As per Azure document I'm not sure but document post limit per batch only `1000` allowed but for testing purpose I'm passed the `0 documents in  IndexBatch.New(actions);`

Then Azure throws the exception.

```
'The request is invalid. Details:
 actions: No indexing actions found in the request. Please include between 1 and 32000 indexing actions in your request.
'
```

And if I passed the `32001` documents in per `IndexBatch.New(actions);`

Then Azure throws the exception.

```
The request is invalid. Details: actions: Too many indexing actions found in the request: 32001. Please include between 1 and 32000 indexing actions in your request.
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-data-import#pushing-data-to-an-index), the limit is 1000 documents or 16MB whichever comes first.

> This approach is more flexible than the pull model because you can
>   upload documents individually or in batches (**up to 1000 per batch or
>   16 MB, whichever limit comes first**). The push model also allows you to
>   upload documents to Azure Cognitive Search regardless of where your
>   data is.

Comment: But what is the limit `push` document in the index?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `limit push document in the index`? Do you mean max number of documents in an index?

Comment: I want to upload the document in the azure server but what is the max limit to upload document in one `IndexBatch.New(actions)` Batch? as per the document, Azure said 1000 but it's also allowed 32000 max? so it's official or something else?

Comment: As per the documentation, the limit is 1000. I’m not sure from where the SDK is getting this 32000 limit.

Comment: Yes, it's true but way it's allowed the `32000` that the question I'm not getting any references related this in azure server.

Comment: One thing you could do is trace the request/response through Fiddler and see if the error is returned by the REST API itself.

Comment: Sure we will check and get back to you :) thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If I'm posting data in azure server it's allowing 32000 documents in One batch it's true?

Comment: The limit of 1000 is the officially supported maximum and what you should use in your application. The fact that the actual limit is higher right now does not mean it will work in the future.